# IOS: How to Keep running background service even application is in the foreground, background, and Killed In IOS using Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have used "flutter_foreground_task" flutter lib to sync data from the server to local Db in the background, foreground, and after a kill. It is working perfectly in Android but in the case of IOS, it's only working in Foreground once the application sends to the background or kills the application our sync process has stopped. we need to sync in our customised intervals like 5,10,15,30,60,180,360, and 720 Minutes.

In IOS, it's only working in Foreground once the application sends to the background or kills the application our sync process has stopped

Comment: If you will search you will find that just isn't how iOS works. You cannot keep running tasks in the background, especially if the user kills the app and you cannot specifiy specific execution intervals. You can schedule a background sync function and when that runs it can schedule the next one, but the precise time of execution cannot be guaranteed. iOS will determine when to run based on factors like the battery charge state, how often your app runs in the background, how much work it does in the background and how often the user uses your app.

Comment: In general, constant syncing of data like this is not an efficient approach. It is typically better just to sync data when your app returns to the foreground, otherwise you have wasted battery on updates that the user may not care about.